# How to get englishPCFG.ser.gz as a single file from Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am far to stupid to get the `stanford-parser.jar` into my build path. Is there a way to obtain just the needed model file `englishPCFG.ser.gz` on its own, and then to `LexicalizedParser.loadModel("/absolute/path/englishPCFG.ser.gz");`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is easy. A jar file is just a glorified zip file.  So using either the jar command or your favorite unzipper, do something like:

```bash
unzip stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar
mv edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz .
rm -rf edu
```

Comment: In order to only do POS tagging like the tagging section here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp, is it needed to use a lexparse as well, or tagger model is sufficient?

Comment: A tagger model is sufficient, but then you need to be running the POS tagger (MaxentTagger).  (That is, while englishPCFG can use the results of another POS tagger, the PCFG model can also do tagging as part of parsing.)